# Saving multiple occurrences of an item in Realm

Tags: swift, date, realm, repeat, eventkit

I am new to coding.

I'm making a finance app and I need to save a recurring transaction with monthly and weekly events.

Here is my Transaction Realm Object:

```
class Transaction: Object {
    
    @objc dynamic var transactionName = ""
    @objc dynamic var transactionDescription: String? = nil
    @objc dynamic var transactionAmount = 0.0
    @objc dynamic var transactionDate = Date()
    @objc dynamic var transactionCategory = ""
    
}
```

Here is my save function:

```
 func saveTransaction() {
        
        let newTransaction = Transaction()
        
        newTransaction.transactionAmount = amount
        newTransaction.transactionName = name
        newTransaction.transactionDescription = desc
        newTransaction.transactionDate = datePicked
        newTransaction.transactionCategory = category
        
        try! realm.write {
            realm.add(newTransaction)
        } 
    }
```

From my research, it seems like EventKit's EKRecurrenceRule is the best way to add repeating items.

I created a function to get a EKRecurrenceRule.

```
func getFrequency(with frequencyString: String) -> EKRecurrenceRule? {
    
        let frequency = frequencyString
        switch frequency {
    case "Daily":
           let occurrenceRule = EKRecurrenceRule(recurrenceWith: EKRecurrenceFrequency.daily, interval: 1, end: nil)
        return occurrenceRule
    case "Weekly":
        let occurrenceRule = EKRecurrenceRule(recurrenceWith: EKRecurrenceFrequency.weekly, interval: 1, end: nil)
        return occurrenceRule
    case "Monthly":
        let occurrenceRule = EKRecurrenceRule(recurrenceWith: EKRecurrenceFrequency.monthly, interval: 1, end: nil)
        return occurrenceRule
    case "Yearly":
        let occurrenceRule = EKRecurrenceRule(recurrenceWith: EKRecurrenceFrequency.yearly, interval: 1, end: nil)
        return occurrenceRule
    default:
        return nil
    }
    }
```

Here is my attempt at the code:

```
func saveMultipleTransactions() {

        let newTransaction = Transaction()

        let pickerText = "Monthly"
        
        var recurrenceRule = getRecurrenceRule(with: pickerText)
                
        //Here's where I get lost:
        var amounts = [amount]
        var names = [name]
        var descs = [desc]
        var datesPicked = [datePicked]
        var categories = [category]

        //I don't know how to apply the RecurrenceRule to datePicked
        datesPicked = recurrenceRule
        

        for date in datesPicked {
            
            //Value of type '...' has to member 'append'
            newTransaction.transactionAmount.append(contentsOf: amounts)
            newTransaction.transactionName.append(contentsOf: names)
            newTransaction.transactionDescription.append(contentsOf: descs)
            newTransaction.transactionAmount.append(contentsOf: datesPicked)
            newTransaction.transactionAmount.append(contentsOf: categories)
            
        }
       
        try! realm.write {
            realm.add(newTransaction)
        }
```

I have 2 questions:

1. Is this the best way to go about this? If so, how do I apply the recurrence rule to datePicked?
2. How do I save a recurring transaction with the same name, description, amount, and category - but different dates?

Thank you so much in advance for the help.

Edit: This is the code that worked for me:

```
var transactionArray:[Transaction] = []

for _ in 1...numberOfTransactionsToAdd {

            let addedTransaction = Transaction()
            
            addedTransaction.transactionAmount = amount
            addedTransaction.transactionName = name
            addedTransaction.transactionDescription = desc
            addedTransaction.transactionDate = datePicked
            addedTransaction.transactionCategory = category
            transactionArray.append(addedTransaction)
        }

let transactionList = List<Transaction>()
        
        
        for transaction in transactionArray {
            
            transactionList.append(transaction)
            
        }
        
        try! realm.write {
            realm.add(transactionList)
        }
```

Comment: The question is a bit vague - you want to *save a recurring transaction with monthly and weekly events*. How do you define a recurring transaction. In other words is the transaction the same amount for the same, category, etc on the same date each month? Week? Also in the `saveMultipleTransactions` function it's named *transactions* plural but you're only creating a *single transaction* `let newTransaction = Transaction()`. Lastly your question is *How do I save the transactions to Realm?* and it seems you already know how to save a transaction to Realm in your first example. Can you clarify?

Comment: I updated the question to hopefully make it more clear. I am new to coding, so I don't know how to save multiple transactions. Would it be something like `let newTransactions = [Transactions]()`? I tried doing that, but couldn't access the `newTransactions.transactionDate` property. Thanks.

Comment: I think the problem is the naming. A Realm object isn't a Realm *objects* (plural), it's singular. In other words a Realm object is Dog, not Dogs. To clarify and in addition to, a Realm Results or List object can contain multiple other Realm objects. e.g. `let dogList = List<DogClass>()` is a List object that contains multiple dogs. If you want multiple transactions, you would instantiate each one `let t0 = Transaction()` and `let t1 = Transaction()` etc. Now you have two transactions; t0 and t1. Going through the [Getting Started Guide](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/) may clear up a lot.

Comment: Thanks Jay, I was able to create the Realm object list and append an array to it. I edited my original question with the code that worked for me.

Comment: Glad you have that working! A couple of notes. You can actually directly add objects to a List so you could simplify the code by doing that. Also: Arrays and Realm Collections. Realm collections are live updating; meaning that if a property in an object included in a collection changes, it automatically changes in code. - which is super cool and powerful. However, if you are keeping objects in an array, it looses that live-updating ability. Also, Realm Collections are lazily loaded, saving on memory footprint. So - the take away is to use Results and List objects as much as possible.